# How to add img into a plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I started constructing my first Wordpress plugin but got an issue... 
I've a folder-file structure like that:

- PluginFolder/

  - TemplateFolder/

    - img/
  - my files php

How can I use the /img/ folder in my plugin? I tried the URL with  but didn't works form me.

I don't know whether it is necessary to use any WordPress-specific function, like the bloginfo('template_url') or so.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    echo '<img src="' . plugins_url( 'img/image.png', __FILE__ ) . '" > ';
?>
```

here is the link how to add images or any other files from plugin folder

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem? See [answer]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but not works in my code :(